# default user agent for android http post?

Tags: android, http-post

I am fully aware of the fact that one can change the default user agent of an android while or before it does an HTTP post. 
But what I am wondering is that if the developer does not set a custom user agent or left the whole user agent criteria unchanged/untouched what would the default User agent be? will it be the same as androids default browser? or would it be something different? I am also aware of the question being too broad as there are millions of devices in planet Earth, not sure about other planets lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is not the same as the Browser, and instead depends on the API you are using. In *Volley*, it is set to "volley", and in other cases (like using `HttpURLConnection`) it may be NULL and need to manually set it using `SetRequestProperty`.